# layout with vertical bar from base of tab to top of footer

Tags: html, css

This fiddle...

http://jsfiddle.net/jeljeljel/5BSva/6/

Shows a layout I am trying to achieve.  I want the vertical bar from the base of the tab to extend to the footer.  I thought I had this fixed but when the content of the page exceeds the vertical height, the vertical bar does not adjust.

Is there a way to change this fiddle so that the vertical bar always extends to the footer?

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header">
        HEADER
    </div>
    <div class="body">


        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="tabcontrol">
            <li class="active"><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane active" id="home" style="">
                <div class="navigation" style="">
                    navigation<br />
                    navigation<br />
                    navigation<br />
                </div>

                <div class="content">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>some information</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>some information</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>some information</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>some information</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>some information</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>some information</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>some information</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>some information</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>some information</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>some information</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>some information</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>some information</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>some information</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>some information</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>some information</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>some information</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>some information</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>some information</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>some information</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>some information</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>some information</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>some information</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>some information</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>some information</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>some information</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>some information</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>some information</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>some information</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>some information</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>some information</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


    </div>
    <div class="push">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="footer center">
    <div style="border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(174, 174, 201); background-color: #fff;"></div>
    <div>
        FOOTER
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
        .body {
            border: 1px solid rgb(174, 174, 201);
            border-top: 5px solid rgb(174, 174, 201);
            border-bottom: 5px solid rgb(174, 174, 201);
            border-left: 2px solid rgb(174, 174, 201);
            border-right: 2px solid rgb(174, 174, 201);
            padding-bottom: 1000px;
            margin-bottom: -1000px;
        }

        /* Sticky Footer by Ryan Fait (http://ryanfait.com/) */
        * {
            margin: 0;
        }

        html, body {
            height: 100%;

        }

        .wrapper {
            min-height: 100%;
            height: auto !important;
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0 auto -50px auto; /* the bottom margin is the negative value of the footer's height */
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        .footer {
            height: 50px;
            background-color: red;
        }

        .footer, .push {
            height: 50px; /* .push must be the same height as .footer */
            clear: both;
        }

        form {
            height: 100%;
        }
        /* Sticky Footer by Ryan Fait (http://ryanfait.com/) */

        .navigation {
            float: left;
            width: 150px;
            border-right: 3px solid rgb(174, 174, 201);
            padding-top: 10px;
            white-space: nowrap;
    position:absolute;

bottom:50px;
    top:65px;
        }

        .content {
            padding-top: 10px;
    margin-left:160px;
        }

        .nav {
            margin-bottom: 0px;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minimal amount of css you would need to achieve this is to add `position: relative` to `.tab-pane` and then adjust the top- and bottom-values for `.navigation`. This is what is needed for the absolute positioning of the latter to have any effect.

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/5BSva/11/

Comment: Yes, that works for when the contents stretch beyond the page.  However, if you remove the contents so the viewport doesn't scroll, then the vertical bar doesn't go all the way to the footer.  See this example...http://jsfiddle.net/jeljeljel/5BSva/12/.  Is there a way to accomplish this so that the vertical bar drops to the footer always?